# Cron Scripts readiness check failed. Found non-writable path(s)

Tags: cron, magento2

I have a cron script error in the Readiness Check of Magento 2.
It says "Error from Updater Application Cron Script:

Found non-writable path(s):
C:\wamp64\www\nypomnichannel/app/design/adminhtml/Magento"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYGNq.png)

I have checked the path and there isn't a file called Magento in adminhtml.
Is there supposed to be a file there? How do I solve this error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error and finally solved it by creating a folder named Magento in app/design/adminhtml.

Comment: In my case I go the error: found non-writable path(s): /var/www/html/nginx.conf.sample. This file didn't exist so I created it using nano and voila!